# No unspecified launch error only if a loop is unrolled?

Tags: c++, cuda

Updated: The title is misleading. Originally I could make the error disappear by unrolling the `block` loop in the code below. Now, even a simple code change lets it disappear. (See code example below).

Background:

An CUDA C kernel implementation of a Cholesky decomposition of a 12x12 matrix results in a quite large CUDA kernel (280 code lines, lots of loops).

I reproduced the error with a reduced setup (code below). NVCC (CUDA 4.2) invoked with

```
nvcc -arch sm_20 -o main main.cu
```

executed on Fermi architecture on Linux:

```
kernel call: unspecified launch failure
```

The kernel body contains a conditional preprocessor block `#if 1`, `#else`, `#endif`. I inserted this to easily switch between a working and non-working version. Compiling the first alternative results in the `unspecified launch failure`. Whereas the second alternative runs fine.

The tricky part is, that the code actually executed should be the same in either case. (hasOrderedRep is true!!)

One can still make the error disappear even when the `#if 1` statement is left untouched. Therefor the `block` loop must be unrolled. This is where the title originates from.

```
#include "cuda.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

/////////////////////////////////////
//
// First some basic types I need
// Implementation of a templated
// scalar and complex number

template<class T> class RScalar
{
public:
  __device__  RScalar() {}

  __device__  ~RScalar() {}

  template<class T1>  __device__   
  RScalar(const RScalar<T1>& rhs) : F(rhs.elem()) {}

  template<class T1>  __device__
  RScalar(const T1& rhs) : F(rhs) {}

  template<class T1> __device__ inline
  RScalar& operator=(const RScalar<T1>& rhs)  {
    elem() = rhs.elem();
    return *this;
  }

public:
  __device__ T& elem() {return F;}
  __device__ const T& elem() const {return F;}

private:
  T F;
};



template<class T> class RComplex
{
public:
  __device__  RComplex() {}

  __device__  ~RComplex() {}

  template<class T1, class T2>  __device__
  RComplex(const RScalar<T1>& _re, const RScalar<T2>& _im): 
    re(_re.elem()), im(_im.elem()) {}

  template<class T1, class T2>  __device__
  RComplex(const T1& _re, const T2& _im): re(_re), im(_im) {}

  template<class T1>  __device__
  RComplex(const T1& _re): re(_re), im() {}

  template<class T1>
  __device__ inline
  RComplex& operator*=(const RScalar<T1>& rhs) 
    {
      real() *= rhs.elem();
      imag() *= rhs.elem();
      return *this;
    }

  template<class T1>
  __device__ inline
  RComplex& operator-=(const RComplex<T1>& rhs) 
    {
      real() -= rhs.real();
      imag() -= rhs.imag();
      return *this;
    }



  template<class T1>  __device__ inline
  RComplex& operator/=(const RComplex<T1>& rhs) 
    {
      RComplex<T> d;
      d = *this / rhs;
      real() = d.real();
      imag() = d.imag();
      return *this;
    }


public:
  __device__ T& real() {return re;}
  __device__ const T& real() const {return re;}

  __device__ T& imag() {return im;}
  __device__ const T& imag() const {return im;}

private:
  T re;
  T im;
};


template<class T> __device__ RComplex<T>
operator*(const RComplex<T>& __restrict__ l, 
      const RComplex<T>& __restrict__ r) 
{
  return RComplex<T>(l.real()*r.real() - l.imag()*r.imag(),
             l.real()*r.imag() + l.imag()*r.real());
}


template<class T> __device__ RComplex<T>
operator/(const RComplex<T>& l, const RComplex<T>& r)
{
  T tmp = T(1.0) / (r.real()*r.real() + r.imag()*r.imag());

  return RComplex<T>((l.real()*r.real() + l.imag()*r.imag()) * tmp,
             (l.imag()*r.real() - l.real()*r.imag()) * tmp);
}


template<class T> __device__ RComplex<T>
operator*(const RComplex<T>& l, const RScalar<T>& r)
{
  return RComplex<T>(l.real()*r.elem(), 
             l.imag()*r.elem());
}

//
//
//////////////////////////////////////////////



#define REALT float
#define Nc 3

struct PrimitiveClovTriang
{
  RScalar<REALT>   diag[2][2*Nc];
  RComplex<REALT>  offd[2][2*Nc*Nc-Nc];
};

__global__ void kernel(bool hasOrderedRep, int * siteTable, 
               PrimitiveClovTriang* tri)
{
  RScalar<REALT> zip=0;
  int N = 2*Nc;
  int site;


  //
  // First if-block results in an error,
  // second, runs fine! Since hasOrderedRep
  // is true, the code blocks should be
  // identical.
  //
#if 1
  if (hasOrderedRep) {
    site = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + 
      blockDim.x * gridDim.x * blockIdx.y + 
      threadIdx.x;
  } else {
    int idx0 = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + 
      blockDim.x * gridDim.x * blockIdx.y + 
      threadIdx.x;
    site = ((int*)(siteTable))[idx0];
  }
#else
  site = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + blockDim.x * gridDim.x * blockIdx.y + threadIdx.x;
#endif

  int site_neg_logdet=0;
  for(int block=0; block < 2; block++) { 
    RScalar<REALT> inv_d[6];
    RComplex<REALT> inv_offd[15];
    RComplex<REALT> v[6];
    RScalar<REALT>  diag_g[6];
    for(int i=0; i < N; i++) { 
      inv_d[i] = tri[site].diag[block][i];
    }
    for(int i=0; i < 15; i++) { 
      inv_offd[i]  =tri[site].offd[block][i];
    }
    for(int j=0; j < N; ++j) { 
      for(int i=0; i < j; i++) { 
    int elem_ji = j*(j-1)/2 + i;
    RComplex<REALT> A_ii = RComplex<REALT>( inv_d[i], zip );
    v[i] = A_ii*RComplex<REALT>(inv_offd[elem_ji].real(),-inv_offd[elem_ji].imag());
      }
      v[j] = RComplex<REALT>(inv_d[j],zip);
      for(int k=0; k < j; k++) { 
    int elem_jk = j*(j-1)/2 + k;
    v[j] -= inv_offd[elem_jk]*v[k];
      }
      inv_d[j].elem() = v[j].real();
      for(int k=j+1; k < N; k++) { 
    int elem_kj = k*(k-1)/2 + j;
    for(int l=0; l < j; l++) { 
      int elem_kl = k*(k-1)/2 + l;
      inv_offd[elem_kj] -= inv_offd[elem_kl] * v[l];
    }
    inv_offd[elem_kj] /= v[j];
      }
    }
    RScalar<REALT> one;
    one.elem() = (REALT)1;
    for(int i=0; i < N; i++) { 
      diag_g[i].elem() = one.elem()/inv_d[i].elem();
      //      ((PScalar<PScalar<RScalar<float> > > *)(args->dev_ptr[ 1 ] ))[site] .elem().elem().elem() += log(fabs(inv_d[i].elem()));
      if( inv_d[i].elem() < 0 ) { 
    site_neg_logdet++;
      }
    }
    RComplex<REALT> sum;
    for(int k = 0; k < N; ++k) {
      for(int i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
    v[i].real()=v[i].imag()=0;
      }
      v[k] = RComplex<REALT>(diag_g[k],zip);
      for(int i = k+1; i < N; ++i) {
    v[i].real()=v[i].imag()=0;
    for(int j = k; j < i; ++j) {
      int elem_ij = i*(i-1)/2+j;    
      v[i] -= inv_offd[elem_ij] *inv_d[j]*v[j];
    }
    v[i] *= diag_g[i];
      }
      for(int i = N-2; (int)i >= (int)k; --i) {
    for(int j = i+1; j < N; ++j) {
      int elem_ji = j*(j-1)/2 + i;
      v[i] -= RComplex<REALT>(inv_offd[elem_ji].real(),-inv_offd[elem_ji].imag()) * v[j];
    }
      }
      inv_d[k].elem() = v[k].real();
      for(int i = k+1; i < N; ++i) {
    int elem_ik = i*(i-1)/2+k;
    inv_offd[elem_ik] = v[i];
      }
    }
    for(int i=0; i < N; i++) { 
      tri[site].diag[block][i] = inv_d[i];
    }
    for(int i=0; i < 15; i++) { 
      tri[site].offd[block][i] = inv_offd[i];
    }
  }
  if( site_neg_logdet != 0 ) { 
  }

}




int main()
{
  int sites=1;

  dim3  blocksPerGrid( 1 , 1 , 1 );
  dim3  threadsPerBlock( sites , 1, 1);

  PrimitiveClovTriang* tri_dev;
  int * siteTable;
  cudaMalloc( (void**)&tri_dev , sizeof(PrimitiveClovTriang) * sites );
  cudaMalloc( (void**)&siteTable , sizeof(int) * sites );
  bool ord=true;

  kernel<<< blocksPerGrid , threadsPerBlock , 0 >>>( ord , siteTable , tri_dev );

  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  cudaError_t kernel_call = cudaGetLastError();

  cout << "kernel call: " << string(cudaGetErrorString(kernel_call)) << endl;
  cudaFree(tri_dev);
  cudaFree(siteTable);

  return(0);
}
```

Note that siteTable contains uninitialized data. That's fine since its not used. I need it to make the error appear.

Update:

Just tried on a different machine which has CUDA 4.0 installed. There the error does not appear (same Fermi card model). Might be really a NVCC bug of CUDA 4.2. Since they switched to LLVM from CUDA 4.1 this is likely to be a bug.

Comment: Unspecified launch failure usually means out of bounds memory access is detected by the hardware during execution. Try running the kernel with cuda-memcheck and see what it says. Also, if the kernel doesn't actually use shared memory, then all you are doing by specifying 48k in the launch is ensuring that only one block per SM will ever run concurrently. I doubt that is what you actually want to do, is it?

Comment: Rolled version, 0KB smem kernel call: cuda-memcheck says "Out-of-range Shared or Local Address". Pretty sure the code is okay. When unrolling the outer loop it runs fine.

Comment: Is there a way to tell the offending command/address ?

Comment: If you compile the kernel with debugging symbols, I am pretty sure cuda-memcheck will report the line number and address of the detected violation.

Comment: I compiled the kernel with `-G`. The error does not show anymore. Very strange!

Comment: No that makes sense, although it seems my advice about debugging symbols wasn't correct. Compiling with debugging symbols will cause a spill of shared memory to local memory so the debugger can access it. So it is definitely in the shared memory access somewhere. I can't recall what incantation of options will force cuda-memcheck to report where the violation is occurring, and I am not near a CUDA capable machine to check. Just out of interest, what hardware are you using (I guess Fermi on Linux)?

Comment: There is no access to shared memory in my kernel. Not once the `__shared__` is used. Still sure its access to smem?

Comment: Almost certainly it is. Shared memory using the same on-die space as L1 cache and the hardware won't let an application overwrite the cache, it will generate a protection fault. But if you aren't using it, as you say, then you could easily remove it and see what happens. It is getting to the point where you might have to post some code if you want help, or work on a reduced repro case which shows the problem if you can't/won't post the whole kernel.

Comment: I am having trouble reproducing the error when using a reduced repro case. The only big change i see is that i don't use a shared library to map the kernel into process memory. The reduced setup is just a 1-filer. Still working on it ...

Comment: @talonmies What do you mean with "you could easily remove it and see what happens"? I launch the kernel now with smem=0 and smem is not used. But still the error shows in the case where the for-loop is there.

Comment: I mean completely remove all shared memory variables from the kernel. If you don't use them, they shouldn't be there. But I really don't think this debugging in comments is going to get you much further. It is probably time to post some code.

Comment: @talonmies please find some code above

Answer (score 1):

This problem appeared to be caused by a subtle compiler bug in an early release of the LLVM based CUDA toolchain. The error doesn't reproduce on more modern versions of the toolchain (CUDA 6.x and 7.x).

[This answer has bee added as a community wiki entry from comments and edits to get the question off the answered list for the CUDA tag]